# How data is fetched: max.poll.records and the offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As per my current understand of Kafka, data is stored and each "store location" is identified by "offset" (numerical value).

I came across this parameter --> `max.poll.records`

Suppose the value of `max.poll.records` is 5, what does this mean? Does it mean that it will read total of `FIVE` "store locations" in one go(for example, will it try to fetch data from offsets 101, 102, 103, 104, 105).

Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are correct, each record is assigned an offset in a partition.

The `max.poll.records` settings ([docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)) allows to define the maximum number of records that the consumer will return each time your application calls [`poll()`](http://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#poll-java.time.Duration-). This is a maximum, it can return that or less.

Note that this does not directly controls how much data is fetched from the cluster as this settings is applied on the client side. This is just to control the number of records return by `poll()`.

In the background, the consumer could have fetched more data, to be ready to be returned next time the application calls `poll()`. How much data is retrieved by the consumer is determined by `fetch.min.bytes`, `max.partition.fetch.bytes` and `fetch.max.bytes`.

This settings allows you to control the pace of your application as you can only have to process `max.poll.records` at once even if there's a large number of records available.

Comment: Thanks for the time and answer. I  will check the links that you provided. I got a doubt:  Does "one record" mean a "single message" or it can have multiple "messages" inside it?

Comment: 1 record = 1 message. I'ts Batches that can contain multiple records

Comment: Thanks again. BTW, is there a way to check the size of individual records?

Comment: as a consumer application, no. It has to fetch the record to get its size

Comment: I have one more question which I have for kafka streams . How can i notify you?

Comment: Please ask another StackOverflow question

Comment: Here it is --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379412/how-many-times-kafka-stream-invokes-poll-for-fetching-records-from-kafka-topic