# How many times kafka stream invokes poll() for fetching records from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand `kafka stream processor` a bit more. I want to know what is the `frequency of polling` by a kafka stream processor for fetching the data from kafka.

As I understand kafka stream processor internally creates a kafka Consumer client which fetches the data from kafka (and it invokes `poll()`).

So when first time `poll()` is called, what is the next time it would be called again to fetch data from kafka? Does it happen many times per second ? How can I know how many times poll() has been called (for fetching data from kafka).

Any help in understanding this would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no absolute number on how often `poll()` is called. There are multiple factors that impact how often `poll()` is called. As a simplified model, you can assume that `poll()` is called, fetches N records, and is called again after all N records are processed.

Kafka Streams collects metrics that tell you how often `poll()` is called though, so you can easily monitor it: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/monitoring.html

Comment: what would be a closer model to reality ? When does Kafka stream actually poll ? If a sub-topology has 3 KTable Processor in row for some reason, which have commit interval and buffer, for  a record to be pushed out, it would take that  record to go trough all processor, i guess. That means assuming the cache never get full, the next poll would happen after that record has gone trough all 3 commits, or one processor commit would do ? and then poll can happen again ?

Comment: It's more complicated. If KafkaStreams calls `poll()`, it first puts all records into an internal buffer. Afterwards, it takes those records out of the buffer for processing. It will process X record before calling poll() again -- and it dynamically adjusts X depending on the time (wall-clock) it took to process X records, and the configures "max poll interval". The reason is, that we don't want to miss calling poll and dropping out of the group. If we did not process all record from the buffer, we might put more record into the buffer after the second poll() etc.

Comment: The internal buffer also has a size limit -- if we reach the size limit, we pause() the corresponding partition, but would still call poll regularly, to maintain consumer group membership. For this case, we don't get new data from poll and the internal buffer shrinks (until we resume() the partition).